# ASP.NET User.IsInRole() with trusted-domain memberships

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-identity

I have a .NET Framework 4.7.2 MVC 5 site that is using Windows Authentication to authorise access to actions based on AD group membership.  This works fine for a single domain, but we have domain trusts in place and ASP does not seem to resolve memberships from other domains.

e.g.
Two domains:  `Parent` and `Leaf`
The site runs in the Parent domain, which has local security groups setup: `SiteAccess-L`.
`SiteAccess-L` contains a single member `Leaf\SiteAccess-G`, which in turn has our user `Leaf\User`.

When I dump the contents of `HttpContext.User.Identity.Groups` (casting through `WindowsIdentity`), I can see all the Leaf domain groups that the user is a member of, but not any of the Parent domain groups.  This only happens for remote users, if I access the site locally, it seems to work.

Running a simple C# app on the desktop of the web server with the same user account and calling `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` will bring me back both domain group membership.

Does anybody know what gives here, and how I access the full cross-domain group memberships in MVC?  If I use GetCurrent() in MVC, I get the service-account that the application pool is running under.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a resolution to this, but I don't fully understand why.

The issue it seemed to be with an SPN.  When accessing the web page through a URL such as http://mysite.parent/ and a SPN was in place for this host, the issue described would occur.

Removing the SPN resolved the issue and all groups were viewable by the site.  This is clearly Keberos related, but my understanding isn't deep enough to categorically say for sure.

In the end, the SPN wasn't needed so it could be removed to resolve the issue.  Reference: https://www.aligrant.com/web/blog/2020-09-28_iis__do_i_need_to_use_a_spn